# UNIX - Surround all Column values of CSV with double quotes

Tags: linux, unix, sed, csv, awk

I have data in following format :

```
productType , Description
Oven , Accurate Preheat, good start for the day 
hairDryers , Comes with extended warranty , 50% off
```

**Desired Output:**

```
"productType" , "Description"
"Oven" , "Accurate Preheat, good start for the day" 
"hairDryers" , "Comes with extended warranty , 50% off"
```

I used the following SED command :

```
sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/,/","/g' filename.csv
```

The above command doesnt work if you have **,** and **"** in cell values.

instead its coming out to be :

```
"productType","Description"
"Oven","Accurate Preheat"," good start for the day" 
"hairDryers","Comes with extended warranty "," 50% off"
```

any way to fix this output to get the desired output ?

Comment: In order to be able to answer this question, you should clarify how to interpret commas: sometimes you want to use them as item separators, sometimes they are inside the items. You must specify a disambiguating rule, otherwise no progress is possible.

Comment: commas are interpreted as item separators , and double quotes are used to specify the cell value ,since i am in process of creating a csv which can be rendered as a json file.

In this sample i shared , there are 16+ columns and 900+ rows , the sed command which i used basically added double quotes in the beginning and end of each line , and then replaced comma by ","

but that created a problem when the comma comes inside a cell , in this case , description field and its moving that to another column (because "cell1","cell2" are considered as 2 different cells)

Comment: Mmm... I think you are mistaken: in the input format, some commas are item separators (*i.e.*, the one between `productType` and `Description`) while others, like the one in the sentence `Accurate Preheat, good start for the day`, are not. So how do we know how to break items, if only some commas are to be trusted?

Comment: this data is exported from DB2 database using :

db2 "EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL
select * from table"

I am guessing while exporting this data , the commas (ig they lie inside a cell) could be escaped.

Comment: Downvoted. It is impossible to answer the question on the basis of the information provided.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^,]*) , (.*)/"\1" , "\2"/' input
"productType" , "Description"
"Oven" , "Accurate Preheat, good start for the day"
"hairDryers" , "Comes with extended warranty , 50% off"
```

In all your examples, the first comma is the field separator and the second comma, if any, is part of the second field.  Thus, we separate the input according to the location of the first comma on the line and put quotes around the two parts.

Comment: The CSV file contains 16 columns and 900+ rows , will this work only if the comma comes in column 2 , or if the comma comes in all description fields within any CSV cell ?

Comment: Who says the second comma is not a separator?

Comment: Doesnt work , And its not necessary that description would always be second column 

It really depends on the query fired since the data is coming from db2 database.

All i want is to escape commas from csv.

Comment: @Abhi1005 The question provided no information to determine which commas are field separators and which weren't.  This answer is based on the pattern in examples you showed.  If this pattern doesn't hold, what is the pattern?  How do you determine which commas are field separators and which are not?